# Sync with Google Calendar both ways

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

Do you guys know if Google calendar has any kind of "push" services? Is there a way possible to get all changes for a user's calendar since a particular timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if u use the Updated-min = lastsynctime you will get the correct new, updated, dleeted events aslo..

```
 string formatedDate = "";
        EventQuery query = new EventQuery();
        DateTime? time;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate))
        {
            time = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate);
            formatedDate = string.Format("{0:s}", time);

            // Create the query object:
            query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + service.Credentials.Username + "/private/full?updated-min=" + formatedDate);
        }
        else
        {
            query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + service.Credentials.Username + "/private/full");
        }


        // Tell the service to query:
        EventFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);
        return calFeed.Entries.Cast<EventEntry>();
```

Comment: I have one doubt about sync, i have google events and outlook events... But on what basis can i sync both events.. since Both have different EventId

Answer (score 3):

This page: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html
Contains all the information you need, including examples.

It will show you how to fetch and push items, and how to query items as you have suggested.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I actually was on that document before I post this question. Maybe I miss something, but I don't see any pushing (not pulling) notification from Google asides from email or SMS nor retrieve calendar changes since a timestamp.

Comment: For example: if today an user updates his yesterday's entry, how will i know that this user had made the change to the past dates' entries? therefore, it will be good to know all the changes since a particular time stamp. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's much help, but in the past I used to sync google calendar with outlook. In outlook I added extra data to all the items so I could compare them with the online items and detect changes/updates like that. I'd give you the code, but sadly it's long gone.. was 2 years ago, to sync multiple gcalendars with outlook.

Comment: I have one doubt about sync,  i have google events and outlook events... But on what basis can i sync both events.. since Both have different EventId.

Comment: The link is not valid anymore

Answer (score 2):

question was asked as of 2010, but as on 2013 i google has released push notification service which allows notify on your service URL whenever there is any manual change in Events

Check documentatoin from google

> https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

sure

```
var service = new CalendarService(domainName);
service.setUserCredentials(email, pwd);

// Create the query object:
EventQuery query = new EventQuery();
query.Uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{0}/private/full", email));

// Tell the service to query:
EventFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);
return calFeed.Entries.AsEnumerable().Cast<EventEntry>().Where(entry => ???);
```

in 'query' object u can add condition u want such as 'query.StartDate'

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i think this gets me all the entries after that startDate, but what I want is the all entries (past, present and future) added/updated after a particular time stamp.